# When a has_many associated object is created does the parent get automatically saved in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model `Chat` which `has_many` messages.

My question is quite a simple one. When I create a new message for the associated chat does RoR automatically call `save!` on the parent `Chat` object, or do I need to add `chat.touch` in a callback on the `Message` model?

On my `Message` model I have `belongs_to :chat, counter_cache: true`. Does this also affect whether the `Chat` gets saved after message create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `counter_cache` does not make a difference.

If you want your `Chat` to be touched when you modify a `Message` you can add `touch: true` to your `belongs_to` definition.

```rb
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :chat, counter_cache: true, touch: true
end
```

However this only updates the `updated_at` and `messages_count` columns and calls `after_touch`, `after_commit` and `after_rollback` callbacks. ([source](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.1.3.1/ActiveRecord/Persistence/touch))

If you want it to execute `save` callbacks, you can call `save` from the `after_touch` callback:

```rb
class Chat < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :messages
  after_touch :save
end
```

Or consider moving your logic to the `after_commit` callback.

Comment: Thanks Jan, this is a super helpful answer and taught me alot!